# Azure Site-to-Site VPN to Cyberoam cannot ping Azure VM from local VPN PC

Tags: azure, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

I've set up Azure site-to-site VPN to Cyberoam following [these](http://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=2936&Lang=1) instructions.

The problem is that I can ping the local PC through the Azure VM but I cannot ping/access the 
shared folder/rdp of the VM from local PC.

I tried disabling firewalls on both system but still with no luck.

Please Note that I used the exact setting on Cyberoam VPN setting given on the instructions I also add rule to allow any/any through firewall.

Edit 1:

Additional information: Cyberoam Version - Cyberoam CR100ia 10.04.2 build 527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by removing NAT Policy for outbound traffic LAN to VPN.